# What does the 'won't in "Won't somebody help me chase the shadows away" mean? Is it supposed to be 'want'?

Tags: questions, subjunctives, lyrics

I have a question about the lyrics of "Gimme Gimme Gimme (A Man After Midnight)" sung by ABBA.

I wonder about a sentence "Won't somebody help me chase the shadows away".
http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/abba/gimmegimmegimmeamanaftermidnight.html

What does the "Won't" mean?
When I first saw this sentence, I thought it was a mistake for "Want".

If the "Won't" is correct, what is the meaning and the nuance of the sentence?
If the "Won't" is incorrect, what is the true word?

Comment: "Won't" = "Will not".

Comment: @Mick Does the woman not expect someone to help her?

Comment: She is just asking for help and so far, she hasn't found anyone.

Comment: The song is about a woman being alone, and she's wondering if there isn't a man to keep her company. "Won't somebody help me chase the shadows away" = "*Will* somebody help me chase the *loneliness* away"

Comment: @Peter I vaguely catch the meaning but not clear... Why was the not of "Won't" necessary and why did you remove the "not" from your second sentence?

Comment: If someone asks you "Won't you help us?" = "Will you not help us?" = "Will you help us?"

Comment: @Peter I clearly understood! "Won't you help us?" = "Will you help us?" I got it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using negatives in a yes-no question, especially a contracted form can be interpreted the same as the positive ("Won't you help me?" == "Will you help me?") but often with a different emphasis or expected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter explained in the comments, the core meaning of "Won't somebody help?" is actually "Will somebody help?"  That is, both are asking for help.

The core difference is in the connotations:

"Will somebody help" is a simple request for assistance.
"Won't somebody help" is both a request for assistance and a statement / complaint that you have been needing help for a while, but nobody has helped you yet.